# Make table using mean of a column in R

Tags: r

I have following data frame:

```
test <- data.frame(Gender = rep(c("M","F"),5), Death = c(1981:1985), Age = c(21:30))
```

and I wanted to know how can I reproduce following results using command `table` rather than `ddply`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(test, c("Gender", "Death"), summarise, AgeMean = mean(Age))
  Death AgeMean
1  1981    23.5
2  1982    24.5
3  1983    25.5
4  1984    26.5
5  1985    27.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `aggregate`...

```
aggregate( Age ~ Death , data = test , FUN = mean )
#  Death  Age
#1  1981 23.5
#2  1982 24.5
#3  1983 25.5
#4  1984 26.5
#5  1985 27.5
```

Comment: So, you mean there is no correspondence to this using exactly "table" command?

Comment: I have presented most of my informative data using table and that way will be easier for me to print final results. But thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Or you could also use `summaryBy` from the `doBy` package:

```
summaryBy(Age ~ Death,data=test,FUN=mean)
Death   Age.mean
1981    23.5
1982    24.5
1983    25.5
1984    26.5
1985    27.5
```

The variable(s) to the left of the `~` is the variable(s) you want to perform the function `FUN=` on (in this case `mean`) and the variable(s) to the right of the `~` is the new level of aggregation you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(Death) %>%
  summarise(Age.mean = mean(Age))
```

I find `dplyr`'s chaining syntax results in very readable code, but that's a personal preference.

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

  Death Age.mean
1  1981     23.5
2  1982     24.5
3  1983     25.5
4  1984     26.5
5  1985     27.5
```